# Password protect folder and allow all subfolders (apache)

Tags: .htaccess, password

I'm trying to password protect one folder on my web site using an .htaccess file with an .htpasswd file. It works and I get it to password protect it.

Can I add something to my folders .htaccess file to allow access to all sub-folders to that folder if the password is entered?

Comment: That should work automatically without any additional work. If it doesn't, please add your .htacess file and relevant log file entries to your post.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think the problem was that on my web page I also have WordPress installed and the 404-pages from wordpress took control over this. It sounds strange but at least I got it to work...